# javascript event only on leaving site

Tags: javascript, onunload

I am creating my own simple stats to record which pages were read and for how long etc.

I then use an ajax call to record the info in a database, it's working using the window.ONBEFOREUNLOAD event, however this creates a database record for each page visited and instead I want to save the page stats to js variables and then only do 1 ajax call when the visitor finally leaves the site.

Is there a way of creating an event listener using pure javascript to detect when the user leaves the site, maybe by evaluation the body's click event ???

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

It is not possible for a browser to provide such an event by default: the browser itself has no awareness of what encompasses an entire site, it's thus impossible for a browser to know when a user leaves a site.

It is easy implement a solution yourself in JavaScript. The implementation is easy, the solution is hard.

You need to consider how you can tell when a user leaves your site. How do you define exit points? Can you define exit points? This is a non-trivial problem. I am not certain a solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
Try the `onbeforeunload` event: It is fired just before the page is unloaded

It also allows you to ask back if the user really wants to leave.

see [this demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx)

alternatively, you can send out an ajax request when he leaves.

**Method 2 :**

```
`if(window.screenTop > 10000)
alert("Window is closed");
else
alert("Window stillOpen");`
```

**Method 3 :**
See this article.
The feature you are looking for is the [onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx)

sample code:

```
  <script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
  }
</script>
```

> All information in this answer are found on StackOverflow.com

Comment: If you mean Leave means Exit, then this will Help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but that's what I am using now and it fires whenever the user leavse any page, what I am looking to do is to detect when the user leaves the SITE not when they click another page on the same site.

Comment: so just Check Current URL, if it contains ur Domain, then don't Give popup or alert, else give, Enclose with try..catch, so whn it closes, the event get fires from catch block.